# How to use where exists in SQL?

Tags: sql, oracle

So this is my question - write a select statement that returns two column from the `gla` table: `acc.num` and `acc.descrp`. the result should have account number that has never been used using an full outer join with `inv.line` table. the never used part has me confused and my code gives me missing keyword error. any ideas?

```
select Account_Number, Account_Description
 from GENERAL_LEDGER_ACCOUNTS gla full join INVOICE_LINE_ITEMS inv
where not exists
(select *
  from 
  where inv.ACCOUNT_NUMBER= Gla.ACCOUNT_NUMBER
 )
   order by Account_number
```

Comment: i think you need to include to join " on " keyword between which column in gla and which column in inv

Comment: how can u show me using my code above, please thank you @HadiHassan

Comment: What are outer joining `gla` to `inv` on? You need to indicate this using an `ON` clause (as @Hadi already indicated)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure to clearly understand your needs, by why didn't you use that instead:

```
select gla.Account_Number, gla.Account_Description
--     ^^^^                ^^^^
--      specify the table alias in case of duplicate columns

from GENERAL_LEDGER_ACCOUNTS gla full join INVOICE_LINE_ITEMS inv
--                               ^^^^^^^^^
--                            ??? see note below

on inv.ACCOUNT_NUMBER = Gla.ACCOUNT_NUMBER
-- ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
--               join clause

where inv.ACCOUNT_NUMBER IS NULL
--    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
-- as this is a full outer join, some rows in `gla`
-- might not have a matching row in `inv`
-- This will keep only those rows

order by Account_number
```

In addition, given your description I would say you only need a `LEFT JOIN` -- not a `FULL OUTER JOIN`.

Answer (score 0):

I am an MSSQL developer but based on this [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_full.asp) sample

you query would become

```
select Account_Number, Account_Description
 from GENERAL_LEDGER_ACCOUNTS gla 
 -- when you use join, you need to specify the relation between which column and which column this join
 full join INVOICE_LINE_ITEMS inv on gla.ACCOUNT_NUMBER= inv.ACCOUNT_NUMBER
where not exists
(select 1
  from 
  where inv.ACCOUNT_NUMBER= Gla.ACCOUNT_NUMBER
 )
```

but from  your question you want all accounts that not used in any invoice, you can do this by simply

```
select Account_Number, Account_Description
 from GENERAL_LEDGER_ACCOUNTS gla 
where not exists
(select 1
  from INVOICE_LINE_ITEMS inv
  where inv.ACCOUNT_NUMBER= Gla.ACCOUNT_NUMBER
 )
```

hope this will help you

Answer (score 0):

You can use `not in`(MSSQL) clause to get this.

```
select Account_Number, Account_Description
from GENERAL_LEDGER_ACCOUNTS 
where ACCOUNT_NUMBER not in(select ACCOUNT_NUMBER from INVOICE_LINE_ITEMS)
```

This is equivalent to not exists query.